# Xcode - how to "export" app solution

Tags: macos, xcode

I am very new to coding, especially to using an IDE like Xcode.

I have a finished app that I'm done compiling and testing it within Xcode itself. I wish to create a file that the user would double-click to run.

How do I get my program out of Xcode as a self-standing application?

Comment: Hello bmike, I was actually looking for a way to create a "finished product". English is not my mother tongue so forgive my wordy-ness... Im done with coding and I wish to create a "self-standing app". Create an .exe if you will

Comment: Perfect Alex - welcome to the site and feel free to mention that english is a second (fifth) language. We try really hard to assist those that make such an effort to communicate. The export option in George's answer is exactly what you need to "make the .exe"

Answer (score 19):

Use **Product** → **Archive** to create a binary of your app. Then go to the Organizer window and optionally validate it. Lastly, export the app to your desktop so you can distribute it as you wish.

Comment: Do you need to be in the apple developer program for it to work?

Comment: @PeterKaminski You don't have to be in the Apple developer program. You can export directly to your computer without signing the app.